# Registering a channel with JMX

Tags: jgroups

A channel can expose its operations and attributes via JMX:

```
JChannel ch=...
ch.connect("cluster");
Util.registerChannel(ch, "jgroups");
```

Attributes and operations can be accessed with a JMX client, e.g. jconsole.

If I open jconsole, I am not able to see the Jgroups MBeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote` to enable JMX?